# R error on a Mac: "family 'Times New Roman' not included in postscript() device"

Tags: r, macos, fonts, ggplot2, postscript

I am using R on a macbook.

This code:

```
postscript("plot.eps")
ggplot(SomeData, aes (x=Cue, y=var1, group=var2, color=var2, shape=var2)) + 
  geom_line(size=0.5) + 
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=Var1-ci, ymax=Var1+ci), width=0.15, size=0.5) +  
  xlab("Var1") + ylab("Var2")+ 
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(600, 675)) + 
  theme(axis.text = element_text(colour = "black")) + 
  scale_colour_manual(values=darkcols) + 
  theme(text = element_text(size=16, family="Times New Roman")) + 
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
dev.off()
```

returns this error:

```
Error in grid.Call(L_textBounds, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  : 
family 'Times New Roman' not included in postscript() device
```

Font family is defined on the plot. Tried defining it with     `postscript(family="Times")` and `postscript(family="Times New Roman")` with no success

Tried `font_import()` / `loadfonts()`, but doing that generates more errors (Plot wont even show up on QUARTZ after doing this)

Checked the disabled fonts in the font folder, Times New Roman is enabled.

Checked the fonts available in R with `names(postscriptFonts())` and it is there.

Like I said, plot looks perfectly in Quartz, but saving it as .eps with postscript generates the mentioned error and a blank file.

Any ideas on how to solve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could also try using the `Cairo` package, which in my experience works better with different fonts.

```
library(Cairo)
cairo_ps("test.eps", family = "Times")
plot(rnorm(100))
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 2):

this seems to work (for Times). So I think you just need to add family="Times" to your postscript() function.

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes (x=cyl, y=disp)) + 
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  theme(text = element_text(size=16, family="Times")) + 
  theme(legend.position="bottom")

postscript("plot.eps", family="Times")
p
dev.off()
```